# Tikz missalign circle - arc fill

Tags: tikz-pgf, circles, fill

I have a problem drawing a circle and then filling a part of it using tikz.

My code (hopefully I `usepackage`'d all the necessary ones for MWE, the header is huge and badly managed):

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[left=3.0cm, right=2.5cm, top=2.5cm,bottom=2.0cm,includeheadfoot]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,calc,decorations.markings,arrows,positioning,intersections,patterns,scopes,datavisualization}
\usepackage{tikzscale}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{fig.tikz}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Contents `fig.tikz`:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.1mm,y=2.0000mm]
   \draw ($(   0.000,   8.138)+(0,3.00)$) coordinate (pnt9) circle (2mm);
   \draw (   0.000,   8.138) -- (pnt9);
   \fill[fill=black] (pnt9) -- ++(0,2mm) arc (90:0.0000:2mm) -- cycle;
   \fill[fill=black] (pnt9) -- ++(0,-2mm) arc (270:173.6690:2mm) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
```

What I get is the following:
[image]

What I get from that, is that the circle's centre is not where all the other elements have it.
Most of the code is generated by another program.

I tried to search for a similar question, but to no avail.

Comment: I obtain a correct figure with your code if I change `tikzfigure` with `tikzpicture`.

Comment: @ignasi Thanks for noticing - corrected the typo. Concerning your comment: I will look up, what is giving me the incorect result in my header file. There must be something messing up ...

Comment: does `figure` even make any sense in `standalone` especially when you are not using any `\caption`.

Comment: @daleif You're right. But I assumed it 'could' be the root of the problem, as I'm scaling the tikzpicture.

Comment: Also, I found the command resulting in the change - the `geometry` package. Added it in the MWE.

Comment: With `standalone` class you don't use `geometry` nor `figure` environments and with `\includegraphics` you can not include a `TiKZ` file. I think you should test your code before posting it to be sure it works as you want.

Comment: @Ignasi Thank you for your thoughtful comments. I assumed I already know something about LaTeX and posted the MWE out of my head. I should not have done that, I agree, and sorry for wasting your time. I changed the documentclass to book and edited the MWE accordingly.

Comment: @Ignasi Also, `includegraphics` with `tikz` works somehow. Did you mean I _should_ not do it, or that I _cannot_ do it?

Comment: @PjancMatuzl that works because of the `tikzscale` package. I tend to make sure my images match my document manually. Then for example I can make sure all line width are the same through out the doc.

Comment: @daleif I'm not really sure what you are talking about. I produce many 200-or-so lines `tikz` pictures for my document from another program and then include them in the main document with `includegraphics` (at least I don't know for a better solution).

Comment: Say you draw a vertical line if width 10pt, and scale this to 0.8, then this line is now 8pt. In a different fig you might have scaled a similar fig by 0.9, giving another line width.

Comment: daleif is pointing out that @Ignasi 's comment doesn't apply since you are loading `tikzscale` which uses `\includegraphics{}` to load Ti*k*Z pictures from external files. This is not the only way. I tend to `\input{}` them and load the `standalone` package so I can also compile the files standalone. But `tikzscale` is a nice-seeming package.

Comment: Why are you making the picture so tiny and then scaling it so much?

Comment: I have a bad feeling about tikzscale.

Comment: @cfr The picture contains more than one circle - their end size is approx. 1-2cm. I scaled it up to better point out the missalign.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The original picture is minute. Ti*k*Z is not very accurate, by default. Hence, when you scale something minute to be many, many, many times its natural size, inaccuracies creep in and rounding errors inevitably degrade the output.

The solution is not to make the original picture so absurdly tiny in the first place. The `x=` and `y=` options were not doing much except in the first line of the picture since specific dimensions were specified everywhere else, so I just eliminated that and multiplied the `3` by `2` in the first line. (Originally, it would be `6mm`. I then removed all the `mm` so that we get something more sensible in terms of natural size. Then it scales up fine.

```
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname-fig.tikz}
\begin{tikzpicture}
   \draw (0,6) coordinate (pnt9) circle (2);
   \draw (0,0) -- (pnt9);
   \fill[fill=black] (pnt9) -- ++(0,2) arc (90:0:2) -- cycle;
   \fill[fill=black] (pnt9) -- ++(0,-2) arc (270:173.669:2) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{filecontents}
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[left=3.0cm, right=2.5cm, top=2.5cm,bottom=2.0cm,includeheadfoot]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikzscale}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{\jobname-fig}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image: bit bigger]

It also looks fine if you don't scale the original but just include it either with `\input{}` or `\includegraphics{}`. Of course, it is a bit on the titchy side of tiny, but it looks fine if you zoom by 1,600% or so - still a bit small, but perfect for all that.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The `x=..,y=..` options are there because I use some big coordinates (as already mentioned, the picture is compiled by another program). I am still accepting your answer, for your efforts :)

Comment: @PjancMatuzl I only removed them really because they were not doing much in the MWE. The `x=` has no effect because the shift is constant and, so, essentially equivalent to zero. So the only effect was on the `3` for the `y`.

Answer (score 1):

After playing around some more by myself, I found that separating the coordinate definition from the drawing of the circle solves the problem too.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.1mm,y=2.0000mm]
  \coordinate (pnt9) at ($(   0.000,   8.138)+(0,3.00)$);
  \draw (pnt9) circle (2mm);
  \draw (   0.000,   8.138) -- (pnt9);
  \fill[fill=black] (pnt9) -- ++(0,2mm) arc (90:0.0000:2mm) -- cycle;
  \fill[fill=black] (pnt9) -- ++(0,-2mm) arc (270:173.6690:2mm) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: Interesting. I assume the inaccuracies affect everything uniformly in this case because there will be some difference in the procedure used to define coordinates implicitly versus explicitly.