# Logarithmic axis with more ticks

Tags: tikz-pgf, ticks, tikz-datavisualization

I have a problem with y-axis of my graph produced with this code:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{datavisualization}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htbp]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \datavisualization [
    scientific axes=clean,
    x axis={length=0.8\textwidth, ticks=some, label={Generation}},
    y axis={length=0.56\textwidth, logarithmic, ticks={minor steps between steps}, grid, label={Costs}},
    visualize as line/.list={best,average},
    legend=north east inside,
    best   ={label in legend={text=best cost}},
    average={label in legend={text=average cost}},
    style sheet=vary dashing
  ]
  data [format=named,set=best, read from file=bestGA.csv]
  data [format=named,set=average, read from file=averageGA.csv]
  ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{GA: graphical representation of costs improvement shown for the average and the best VA.}
\label{fig:GAimprovement:eb_555AICH}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

The files with data: [average.csv](http://www.filehosting.org/file/details/632102/averageGA.csv) and [best.csv](http://www.filehosting.org/file/details/632103/bestGA.csv)

[image: The ticks and the grid are there, only the labels are missing.]

What I would like is for labels to also appear at the minor ticks (i.e. `8*10^6`, `9*10^6` and `1,1*10^7`). I read in the documentation that the minor ticks do not have labels, but is there a workaround?
I already tried `ticks={at={8000000,9000000,11000000}}` to brute force the ticks, but to no avail ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is needed is `ticks and grid={major at={8000000.0,9000000.0,10000000.0,20000000.0}}` to get the desired effect.

[image: wanted result]

However, this is hard-coded now. Does anybody know of a better solution?

Comment: I truly ask myself, why bother posting a question, when after a while I find the answer myself? Happens too often lately - see [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/343810/22742).